# Seeking source for story of someone who communicates from the next world about concepts not understood in this world

Tags: sources-mekorot, olam-haba-world-to-come, story-identification

There is a story of 2 great Rabbis who made a pact between themselves that whoever died first would come back in a dream and tell the other one why certain bad things happened in the world. But when the first Rabbi got to the “Olam Haemet” he no longer had any questions and that is what he told his friend in the dream. I was told that such a story is in the Gemora and/or it was quoted by the Ramban. Does anyone know the source?

Comment: There is a similar story with the wife of the Vilna Gaon making a pact with her friend that whoever would die first would appear to the other in a dream and would relate how great the *olam haemes* is. The friend died first and appeared in a dream telling the Vilna Gaon's wife that the one action of raising her hand to give tzedoko makes all the difference in the *olam haemes*.

Comment: Take a look at this - https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=TiRjDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA164&lpg=PA164&dq=two+rabbis+made+a+pact+to+tell+each+other+about+the+next+world&source=bl&ots=OwBj0HFFXx&sig=ACfU3U2gSPIzSbzP7hCqfMfyvEoB86LYFQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC6Y7Xq5H1AhVG3KQKHWjWD44Q6AF6BAgWEAM#v=onepage&q=two%20rabbis%20made%20a%20pact%20to%20tell%20each%20other%20about%20the%20next%20world&f=false - here the story is attributed to Rav Nachman of Breslov....

Comment: Didn't let me see the whole story, What I have in mind is that when one goes to the Olam Haemet he can no longer report on why bad things happened because in the next world everything appear to be good